# PHP: persistent variable value

Tags: php, static

I have to read a file and do some computation, than save the result of this computation inside a variable.

I just need to do this once. In Java + Servlet I can do this using a servlet container and, for instance, the singleton pattern.

I know that in PHP I can't act like this. Which is the better way to do this? Save the computation (or transfer the data) on DB?

Comment: [apc_cache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php) if you have that installed

Comment: Why can't you do a singleton in PHP?

Comment: @JaredFarrish because the variable will not persist between multiple requests

Comment: @Antonio That's what sessions are for http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php, or do you mean you need a global state for all users?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sessions are relative to a single user, am I wrong?
edit: yes, I need some global state, sorry you edited :)

Comment: @Antonio That's what I asked - you need a global state?

Comment: So you're talking about persistence across requests. Is it a demand that it lives in memory? If so, there's Redis and memcache, and maybe APC? The rough and ready way would be to [`eval(var_export($array_of_goodies));`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). In other words, you can pop what `var_export` outputs to a flat file and then `eval` it back into PHP, lickity split.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it won't work like with Java Servlets. You'll have to find a workaround.

First, I assume that using $_SESSION, $_COOKIE or $_REQUEST in general isn't practicable to you as you want to save the state per server (or per application) and not per 'User Session'.

Using a database sounds practicable in your case. In a regular application design it will be the most common solution.

Also you can do something like this, using the serialization capabilities of PHP:

```
<?php

$resultfile = 'result.dat';
if(!file_exists($resultfile)) {
    $result = compute_result('foo bar');
    file_put_contents($resultfile, serialize($result));
} else {
    $result = unserialize(file_get_contents($resultfile));
}
```

Using PHP's `serialize()` attempt is especially practicable when

- You are in a PHP only environment
- `$result` is a complex datatype but you don't want to create a database structure and map $result too it

If you are not in a PHP only environment you might prefer other serialization formats as JSON or XML.

Also the serialization result can be stored as a string in a database instead of a file. Saving it to a database instead of a file would make the application more scalable as the result would be available to all servers that access the same database (cluster).

In short: I would suggest using a database maybe combined with serialization.

Comment: Just as an additional suggestion: if you need to access this global state using another language (maybe Java), using a format like JSON might be easier.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I updated the answer according to your comment.