# What is the Efficient way for build a chat script without having Server Root Access

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a hosing account. (cPanel or DirectAdmin)
So I don't have root access, i can't use exec() or shell_exec() functions (Blocked by Server Admin).

I know best way for chat is socket programing but it needs Terminal Commands like:

> PHP ./server.php

But i don't have access to the Terminal.

I did too many searches and found some methods but I'm not sure for performance because they are using a Javascript command `setTimeout()` for connecting to the chat database or file.

I think if i used `setTimeout('refresh()',1000)` there is a better way instead of connecting to the chat database every 1 sec.
my method:

```
refresh=function()
{
//there is flag in session, true means there is new message from sender (session_set_save_handler)
//check flag value in the session, if its true then refresh chat database
}
setTimeout('refresh()',1000)
```

**I used a flag because i dont want to connect to the database every 1 sec, maybe there is no new messages from sender, but we're forcing the server to refresh every 1 sec.**

Is my method better or not ? is there a better way for build a chat script without Server Root access?

Thanks alot.
Sorry for bad English

Comment: You could look into websockets, however I dont know how that would work out due to server timeout limit and such. Another possible solution would be to use longpolling. [This](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) gives a nice introductory to the subject.

Comment: Does it have to be created in PHP? `Node.js` can be used to create a very responsive chat server, see: http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/ or google chat and node.js. There are lots of free hosting solutions for `node.js` and it could be linked to from your php pages. Alternatively, solution in php: http://css-tricks.com/chat2/.

Comment: Check out firebase.. Their tutorial is about a chat system.. so you can just use that.. It is client-side only.. https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: I think `node.js` method needs terminal to open a port, i cant open port or install modules

Comment: @Nader There are free hosting solutions for `node.js`, could you host the chat engine portion of your site on one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution will definitely work, using `setTimeout` to check for new messages every second or so. There are other technologies such as [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) although these are not possible in PHP, as stated in the question.

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/chat2/) is an example that uses PHP and stores chat history in an SQL database, the ajax function to get new chat messages:

```
//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
  $.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "update.php",
    data: {  
        'state': state,
        'file' : file
        },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

        if (data.text != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {  
            $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
        }

        document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;

    }  

    instanse = false;
    state = data.state;
    setTimeout('updateChat()', 1);

    },
  });
}
```

As you can see the last line uses `setTimeout` to call the function every 1 second.

Messages are sent separately by a different function:

```
//send the message
function sendChat(message, nickname) {       
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "process.php",
       data: {  
                'function': 'send',
                'message': message,
                'nickname': nickname,
                'file': file
                },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){

       },
    });
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment above, there are some advantages to using server technologies other than PHP. Most PHP solutions use a database to persist chat messages between requests to the server, this creates a lot more server overhead than is really needed, a node.js solution can instead store the messages in an array that stays in memory within the server, and in addition use sockets see [here](https://github.com/uditalias/chat-nodejs) for an example.

**Edit - to cache an sql query in memory**

If you are using MySQL it is possible to prepend your query with a comment to imply that the query should be cached in memory, something like:

```
$res   = $mysqli->query("/*" . MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH . "*/" . "SELECT message FROM chatroom WHERE id = $roomId");
```

For more information see example 1, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php). The example times the queries and could be useful as a benchmark on your Server.

Caching can occur on the server even if the code does not explicitly ask for it, after all the amount of memory required to store the contents of a chatroom is very small - it's only a few lines of text! The example I took the Javascript code from, above, stores the text in a file, which would almost certainly be stored in memory on the Web Server. If the db server is running on the same host as the web site then the request may well not result in any disk activity, making the overhead also very small. The webserver / db connection may also be in memory rather than sockets.

The best solution will very much depend on your server setup, best to get something working, then optimise it. I do know from experience that the `node.js` solution is very fast.

**Edit - Answer to flag question**

Setting a flag in the client Javascript would not work, as other clients could submit messages without the flag for the current client being reset. Setting a flag in the PHP on the server is tricky, persistent variables that are not specific to clients (from sessions or cookies), and not stored in databases have to be saved in files: [PHP: persistent variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074989/php-persistent-variable-value). The `static` keyword is not quite the same as it would be in C or similar language. This is one of the main advantage of using `Node.js`, persistent arrays are very easy to create.

One solution would be to save the messages as `json` in a file, append each new message as it is received, and return the whole file to the user, once a second. The file could be restricted to 100 lines or so, this would ensure that it stays stored in cache memory somewhere (ramdisk, OS disk cache, or at worse hardware cache on the harddisk itself).

Comment: I think Connecting to the database every 1 sec is not good way.
maybe there is no new messages but we check it every 1 sec !

Comment: @Nader yeah, that is a problem with a PHP solution. It is possible to cache database queries in PHP, this would prevent costly database queries unless a new message is posted. This would cause the message history to sit as a list in the memory cache of the PHP server, persisted between client / server requests.

Comment: Thanks henry, can u please give me sample ?

Comment: @Nader I ve added a sample to the answer

Comment: Thanks, i will check it, I'm using PDO not sql, but they are same

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194223/pdo-and-caching-how-to-implement-it-in-a-database-class

Comment: thanks henry i can't give u reputation because I'm new here, i need +16 reputation to use vote up feature :(
but im working on this, i have a question, checking a session flag is better or not ? if sender has not send a message then update.php returns null else it returns a json array ;)

Comment: You can still tick the question as answered, ;). Probably best to ask that as a new question, ;).

Comment: my question is not answered completely, if you look @ my question in last paragraph i ask this : Is my method better or not ? (session flag). anyways can u give me a +1 for my question? I need reputation

Comment: @Nadar I mean the edit in my answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

I once made a simple chatting script when i was still learning web development. You can use following javascript functions to make your little chatting messenger:

Fetch messages from db through ajax after every 1 second

```
function fetchMessage()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    flag_loading=1;
    document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
  /*else if (flag_loading=0)
    {
        document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML="loading..."; 
    }*/
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetchmessage.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

setInterval("fetchMessage()",1000);
```

Server side script fetchmessage.php goes here

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include('connect.php');

    $user_id=@$_GET['user_id'];

    $sql="select m.user_name,m.message,m.post_time from message m where m.user_id='".$_SESSION['current_user']['user_id']."' or m.reciever_id='".$_SESSION['current_user']['user_id']."' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<br><font size=2 color='brown'><b>".$row['user_name'].":</b></font> ".$row['message']."</br>";
        echo "<font size=1 color='blue'>(".$row['post_time'].")</font>";
    }

?>
```

This function sends your message to the other user (chatting with you)

```
    function addMessage(reciever_id, user_id, message) {

    if (message=='') {

        window.alert("Enter some message.");

    } else if (reciever_id=='none') {

        window.alert("Select any friend.");

    } else {

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            document.getElementById('message').value="";
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "addmessage.php?user_id="+user_id+"&message="+message+"&reciever_id="+reciever_id, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

    }
}
```

Server side script addmessage.php goes here

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['current_user'])) {
    header("location:index.php?error=Please Login First!");
}

else {
    $user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
    $message=$_GET['message'];
    $reciever_id=$_GET['reciever_id'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO message VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['current_user']['user_id']."', '".$reciever_id."', '".$_SESSION['current_user']['user_name']."', '".$message."', NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

You can also check for online users/friends using this script

```
    function checkOnline() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById('online_friends').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        //window.alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "onlinefriends.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

setInterval("checkOnline()", 1000);
```

Server side script for onlinefriends.php goes here

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include('connect.php');

    $query_online=mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_status=1 AND user_name!='".$_SESSION['current_user']['user_name']."' ") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_online)) {
    echo "<font size=4 style='font-style:italic; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif'>".$row[0]."</font><br>"; 
    }
?>
```

And ask me if you feel it difficult to implement, i'll help you further :)

Comment: Thanks but its not my answer, I dont want to connect to the database every 1 sec. maybe there is no new messages from sender. connecting to the database is costly

Comment: @Nader If you don't want to connect to DB every second, then you can use **Persistent connections**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't (or can't) use socket, mixing a low-weight response php page with auto refreshing script in each client with jquery ajax in a certain couple of time is best solution. but it's performance is very depended on total of your active chat pages!

for better performance and decreasing server's processing time i think making a custom session handlers for accessing to all of active sessions is a good way to check if any new message has been received for reader instead of checking database every time.

and for saving bandwidth especially in high traffic time you can change JavaScript next setTimeout delay with received response from ajax.

another solution is to set read flag for each message in your database in order to send just new messages with json instead of reloading all of messages in every update.